# How to uninstall UWP apps using SCCM

Tags: uwp, sccm

We pushed the UWP app through the wizard but there is not option to uninstall the app.
How to uninstall the the UWP silently through SCCM

Comment: I'm confused about how you installed your uwp app and what does the wizard refer to? Is the SCCM you mentioned the configuration manager? And why do you want to uninstall app through it? Can you show more details about these questions?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT, yes, Microsoft SCCM. uninstalling the app silently is part of the lifecycle of the app in an enterprise company. If you pushed the app silently, you will also need to uninstall it silently rather than asking every user to uninstall it manually.

Comment: Learn about the process of creating the package and pushing it from here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teju_shyamsundar/2016/05/30/deploy-an-application-from-windows-store-for-business-via-system-center-configuration-manager/

Comment: Unfortunately, SCCM tool does not support uninstalling. And it can run on Admin account not user one while a powershell script will uninstall the UWP app for the current user. that is why i need to find another way or option in SCCM.

Comment: Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/configmgr/apps/deploy-use/uninstall-applications), if you configure the application deployment type with the uninstall command line, deploy the application, and then select the deployment action Uninstall on the Deployment Settings page of the Deploy Software Wizard, can you uninstall the app successfully?